# ajax not retrieving new geoJSON data

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps-api-3, geojson

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [google maps api real time updates with new geojson files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149836/google-maps-api-real-time-updates-with-new-geojson-files)

For some reason when the polygons are regenerated they are still using json_template.json. I would like to refresh with json_template1.json. I think it has to do with my ajax.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

```
    var map;

    function initialize() { 
        var kansas_city = new google.maps.LatLng(39.316858,-94.963194);
        var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: kansas_city,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
            setTimeout(function() { removeSectors() }, 1000);
            setTimeout(function() { updateMap() }, 2000);
            });     
    }

    function removeSectors() {
        if ( allPolygons ) {
            for ( i = 0; i < allPolygons.length; i++ ) {
                allPolygons[i].setMap(null);
            }
        allPolygons.length = 0;
        }
    }

    var data;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'json_template.json', true);
    xhr.onload = function() {
        data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
        sector_callback(data);
    };
    xhr.send();

    function updateMap() {
        var data;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'json_template1.json', true);
        xhr.onload = function(response) {
            data = JSON.parse(response.responseText)
            sector_callback(data);
        };
        xhr.send();
    }

    function createClickablePoly(poly, html) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(poly, 'click', function(evt) {
        infowindow.setContent(html);
        infowindow.setPosition(evt.latLng);
        infowindow.open(map);
        });
    }
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});        

    function sector_callback() {
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();        
        for (var i = 0, len = data.features.length; i < len; i++) {
            var coords = data.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0];
            siteNames = data.features[i].properties.Name; // added for site names
            var path = [];
        for ( var j = 0, len2 = coords.length; j < len2; j++ ){ // pull out each     set of coords and create a map object
            var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[j][1], coords[j][0])
            bounds.extend(pt);
            path.push(pt);

        }

        var polygons = new google.maps.Polygon({
        path: path,
            strokeColor: "#000000",
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 1,
            fillColor: "#000000",
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map
        });
        createClickablePoly(polygons, siteNames);
        //console.debug(siteNames);

        google.maps.event.addListener(polygons, 'mouseover', function() {
        var currentPolygon = this;

        currentPolygon.setOptions({ 
            fillOpacity: 0.45,
            fillColor: "#FF0000"
            })
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(polygons, 'mouseout', function() {
        var currentPolygon = this;
        currentPolygon.setOptions({ 
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
            fillColor: "#000000"
            })
        });

        allPolygons.push(polygons);
        }
    }
    var allPolygons = [];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xhr.onload = function()` must receive a parameter, such as:

```
function updateMap() {
        var data;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'json_template1.json', true);
        xhr.onload = function(request) {
            data = JSON.parse(request.responseText)
            sector_callback(data);
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
```

**Edit:**

You can also use this AJAX function, which is cross-browser compatible:

```
function ajaxLoad(url,callback,plain) {
    var http_request = false;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
        http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (http_request.overrideMimeType && plain) {
            http_request.overrideMimeType('text/plain');
        }
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
        try {
            http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {}
        }
    }
    if (!http_request) {
        alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
        return false;
    }
    http_request.onreadystatechange =  function() {
        if (http_request.readyState == 4) {
            if (http_request.status == 200) {
                eval(callback(http_request));
            }
            else {
                alert('Request Failed: ' + http_request.status);
            }
        }
    };
    http_request.open('GET', url, true);
    http_request.send(null);
}
```

and call it like this:

```
ajaxLoad('json_template1.json',processAjaxResult, true);
```

and then

```
function processAjaxResult(request) {
    alert(request.responseText); //<---- your data is now here!
    //...etc
}
```

Comment: I added the parameter but still updates with the original .json file. I must be missing something. Thank you.

Comment: Actually I am getting the following error: The map doesn't refresh once the second ajax call occurs.       SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
[Break On This Error]  

data = JSON.parse(response.responseText)

Comment: I updated the code above to show what I currently have.

Comment: 1. Where is your JSON object instantiated? (it is not in the code you posted) - 2. What browser are you using? (hopefully not IE).

Comment: It is being instantiated in the first Ajax call when the page loads and again when the updateMap() function is called. At least that is how I understand it. I am using chrome and Firefox but would eventually like to make it compatible with ie. thank you.

Comment: As mentioned earlier, I do not see your JSON object instantiated in the code you posted.

Comment: They are in seperate files would you like me to post a sample of the structures? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you! I'm excited to give it a try this afternoon. Your snippets give me a much better understanding. I am grateful.

Comment: You're welcome. In general it is always a good idea to separate code into small functions that perform each an individual small task. Like that it becomes easier to identify and isolate problems. By the way, if you found the answer useful, feel free to up-vote and/or accept it. ;-)